# Qt: QWebView and QByteArray cause encoding conflict

Tags: qt, encoding, qt4, qwebview, qbytearray

I have been sitting on the same problem for over three days now and I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code.

Im my program, I use a `QWebView` window to represent HTML content. This HTML content is generated on-the-fly, based on user settings. I use `QXmlStreamWriter` to generate HTML file. `QXmlStream` needs a `QIODevice`, so I create a `QByteArray`, write HTML code into it and in the end I create a `QString` out of the `QByteArray`. When I print this code in the `QWebView`, it does not display special symbols (like German Umlauts or Russian letters) correctly. However, if I save the generated code to an HTML file, Firefox opens displays these characters correctly.

The generated HTML contains `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` tag.

I have already tried setting a codec for strings, and converting string to different formats and playing around the `QByteArray` itself. I use Qt 4.7.3. for Windows Desktop with MinGW 4.4.

I guess, I am missing an important point in the encoding story, and I would be grateful for any help! The problem is really annoying and it is preventing me from completing my idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QXmlStreamWriter`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qxmlstreamwriter.html) can very well write to `QString` directly (since it was introduced in Qt 4.3), no need to add the extra chance of getting the encoding wrong with a `QByteArray`.

E.g. this (trivial) snippet works just fine (the source file is encoded in UTF-8):

```
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebView>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString bytes;
    QXmlStreamWriter xs(&bytes);

    xs.writeDTD("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">");
    xs.writeStartElement("html");
    xs.writeStartElement("body");
    xs.writeTextElement("h1", QString::fromUtf8("éëè абвгдеёж 漢字"));
    xs.writeEndElement();
    xs.writeEndElement();

    QWebView w;
    w.setHtml(bytes);
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Without more details of your problem (code snippets and data captures - your source data encoding might not be what you think it is), can't help much more than this.